# Regular expression grouping matching validation

Tags: regex, expression

I want to know whether there is some manner to certify whether a grouping has produced a match. For example, let's see what I want to accomplish with the following 2 strings:

```
string 1: "start magic someword anotherword test end"

string 2: "start test x y z end"
```

I want to get the string that has the keywords `magic` and `test` (both of them). But there are some issues:

- `magic` and `test` may not be continuous one another. For example, `start magic word1 test word2 end`
- `magic` and `test` may not be in that order in the string, i.e. a match should be given for `start magic test end` and for `start test magic end`.

To handle that, I took the following regular expression:

```
start ((w1)*(w2)*\[^(end)])+end
```

... which means:

- The string must start with the word `start` and finish with `end`.
- Match `w1` and `w2` in any order and consume other words that aren't `end` thanks to `[^(end)]`.
- Afterwards, match end.

The problem with that regular expression is that all strings match it because of `[^(end)]` and my need to discard the words between `w1` and `w2` in the actual string.

Putting the regular expression to match string 1, it would be:

```
start ((magic)*(test)*[^(end)])+end
```

... which should match string 1 only (and this is what I want). But string 2 also matches.

Is there any form of checking if the grouping has been matched by the regex engine? Something like `(if \1 != null)` to check that `magic` and `test` keywords has been encountered? I have to do it with regexes because I cannot deal with it in source code. It is intended to work with a tool that is command-line invoked.

Comment: The regex that you have written does something completely different from what you think it does and will only match strings that look something like `start magic*test()n(ddn))(dend`

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This expression will:

- require the string to start with `start` followed by a space
- require the string to end with a space followed by `end`
- must contain both `magic` and `test` in any order
- the words `magic` and `test` must be surrounded by at least one space

`^start(?=\s)(?=.*\smagic(?=\s))(?=.*\stest(?=\s)).*\send(\r|\n|\Z)`

[image]

**Input Text**

```
start magic someword anotherword test end
start test x y z end
start the a magic show with Gob and Tony Wonder who will test till the end
```

**Output

```
[0] => start magic someword anotherword test end
[1] => start the a magic show with Gob and Tony Wonder who will test till the end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I deleted start and end as markers and substitute them for **. The expression now is

`"\*\* [^\*]*(w1|w2)[^\*]*(w1|w2)[^\*]* \*\*"`

to match a string `"** whatever w1|w2 whatever w1|w2 whatever **"`

and not to match a string like `"** whatever w1|w2 ** w1|w2 **"`

@Denomales, can you tell me where you got the image from? thank you